# Authorization header is not send for the subsequent request from Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, authorization, http-authentication

I am trying to access html files protected by basic authentication. Below is the code to do that but I still get the authentication dialog. I checked the fiddler and found that for the first request authorization header is present but for the subsequent requests which is requested to load the .js, css & images the authorization header is not added. This is the reason I am getting the auth dialog. 
Is there a way to add authorization header to the subsequent requests as well?

```
var loader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader(); 
var be:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder(); 
be.insertNewLines = false; 
be.encode("madhur" + ":" + "sharma"); 
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://bazinga/myHtmlFiles/index.html"); 

urlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ be.toString())); 
page.htmlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  If you're creating a new URLRequest for each request, then yes, you have to add the authorization in the header for each time.

Comment: I am making a single request. I am trying to load index.html on a button click. index.html references many resources like script.js,main.css and some images. Request to index.html is send with auth header. But in fiddler I checked that next request is send to load the resource http://bazinga/MyHtmlFiles/main.css. In this particular request there is no authorization header. This is reason I get the authentication dialog box.

Comment: The above solution didn't worked for me. Below is the alternate solution. See related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359670/urlrequestdefaults-setlogincredentialsforhost-not-setting-the-user-pwd-in-autho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution didn't worked for me. Below is the alternate solution.

```
URLRequestDefaults.authenticate = false;
URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost("bazinga.xyz.com", "madhur", "sharma");
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://bazinga.xyz.com/MyHtml/index.html");
htmlControl.htmlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

See related question [URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost not setting the user & pwd in authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359670/urlrequestdefaults-setlogincredentialsforhost-not-setting-the-user-pwd-in-autho)