# URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost not setting the user & pwd in authorization header

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, basic-authentication, urlrequest

I want to access html files which are protected by basic authentication.
I am trying to load this html page using htmlloader and sending the request by urlRequest.
I am using URLRequestDefaults class to set the credentials but when I see the request being send in the fiddler I don't see any authorization header being set by this. 
Am I doing something wrong here. My code is below.

```
URLRequestDefaults.authenticate = false;
URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost("www.xyz.com", "madhur", "sharma");
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://bazinga.xyz.com/MyHtml/index.html");
htmlControl.htmlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Comment: You should either close or answer your other question pertaining to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestDefaults.html#setLoginCredentialsForHost%28%29) more carefully:

> Note that "example.com", "www.example.com", and "sales.example.com" are each considered unique hosts.

In this case, the domains don't match.

Comment: thanks..actually I was giving "www.bazinga.xyz.com" but it was not working..I removed 'www' and just gave 'bazinga.xyz.com' and it started working.